# Клонировать жесткий диск с Ubuintu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, bios

Есть диск с системой Ubuntu 17 на 60 гб и диск с виндой на 1тб. Как сделать копию жесткого диска убунты в раздел диска с виндой?

Comment: Вы хотите стереть винду или о чём речь?

Comment: нет, на том же диске расположить раздел где будет убунта

Comment: Добавить ещё один раздел по соседству с виндой? Тогда создайте новый раздел такого же размера и скопируйте через dd

Comment: я так и сделал, но потом не могу запустить убунту, в биосе нет выбора раздела с ней

Comment: Потому что нужно ещё загрузчик установить на новом диске, загрузившись с LiveCD/LiveUSB

Comment: загружался с лайф сд но как загрузчик поменять не знаю

Comment: http://hostadmina.ru/blog/linux/shell/vosstanovlenie-zagruzchika-grub2.html как восстановить граб.